# Why do batsmen tap their bat on the pitch?

Tags: cricket, trivia

Whenever any batsman comes to the crease, he almost always taps his bat on the pitch. Is there any reason for them to do this? Maybe to make the bowler wait longer to try and put him off? Could there be any other reasons behind it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another reason batsmen will tap on the pitch is to compact the pitch a little where the ball has bounced erratically in the hope of settling it down and restoring more normal bounce.

They will also do it to repair arears where a mini divit has occurred.

Answer (score 2):

Batsman generally would like to check the bounce the pitch has to offer. By tapping the pitch on the probable length the bowler would bowl, the batsman can anticipate the degree of bounce the bowler can produce with his deliveries. This is done many time in Test matches or during extremely long innings, as the pitch responsiveness can vary due to weather and/ or by the wearing out of the pitch.

Answer (score 1):

The batsmen gauge and tap the cricket pitch due to following reasons:

1. To tap some extra grass on pitch,so that it shall not create uneven
   bounce.
2. To make the surface even or to remove any stone or any other particle    from the pitch.
3. To nullify the impact bowlers foot marks can cause, if ball is
   pitched there.